# How Can I Visualize the project files in a Live Share Session Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I've developed in different moments some C# scripts for a game with a friend (We're developing in Unity). Turns out we could've coded at the same time using Live Share in Visual Studio.
So we decided to try it out and it seems to work just fine. But I cannot navigate the files in our project.
That's my screen:

[image]

This is my friend's screen:

[image]

The same thing happens when I share the link to him. But in this case, I can see the whole project in the solution explorer and he can't.
This thing won't happen if I share a different project type though.
e.g: I created a Blazor Web App and we can navigate the files normally, so I think it might be some Unity quirk.

Comment: Maybe similar problem: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/live-share-missing-files/392846

Comment: They didn't solve the problem though. That something that happens with just Unity I think, the docs don't really mention these missing files

Comment: Is your problem solved? You could report   the issue to Developer Community.